# Updated : FirstObject is undefined emberjs array

Tags: ember.js

I need to get firstObject of my carousel and set it as active
this is how I am setting carousel property

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/33/edit) for code

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    carouselData: function () {
        var categories = this.get('content');
        var products = Em.A([]);
        categories.forEach(function (category) {
            category.get('items').then(function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (product) {
                    products.addObject(product);
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(products);
        console.log(products.get('firstObject'));
        return products;
    }.property('content')
});
```

**Update**

@ppcano Thanks for the explanation :). I got what you are asking me to do. return model only when hasMany has fulfilled. and then with computed property save them in carouselData property. but may be I am missing something in implementation the `cdata.get('firstObject')` returns a promise updated jsbin [UPDATED JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/40/edit) in App.Caroure

*update 2*
SOLVED [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/oTIkigAV/44)

Comment: I think, Ember.computed.alias('content.firstObject.items.firstObject') can work.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Since I am in learning stage it will be nice to know why it's not working

Comment: I updated my response. There was a failure on the CP implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the computed property does not work within async execution.

```
category.get('items').then(function (data)
```

The products variable is returned before any data can be pushed into products, because the items must be requested.

You could solve it when you ensure that items are loaded when the property is computed. You could do it in your route model as:

```
model: function(){

    return this.store.find('facture').then(function(factures){

      var productPromises = factures.getEach('items');

      return Ember.RSVP.all(productPromises).then(function(products) {
         return factures;
      }); 

    });

}
```

Then, you could define your CP as:

```
  carouselData: function(){

    var result = Em.A([]);

    this.get('content').getEach('items').forEach(function(items){
      result.pushObjects(items.toArray());
    });

   return result;

 }.property('content.@each.items.@each')
```